# Not able to boot Windows iso on my ubuntu in the Oracle VirtualBox-5.2

Tags: boot, system-installation, virtualbox, windows

I have been stuck at this point for quite a lot time now and didn't get a fix. 
I downloaded the Windows iso file from https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10ISO , i have virtual box 5.2 installed.
So I went to New, created my machine with 2GB RAM allocation and 50GB hard disk allocation. (Tried dynamic and fixed both)
After this, I right clicked on my machine and added the optical drive as my Windows iso file and now, when I open my machine, i should boot. But it isn't.
It says **FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted**

Please, provide me with a fix. It's been 2 days since i'm stuck at this point.
I tried everything i found, removed Virtual box and followed steps given in different tutorials but it isn't working out.

Please help, I'd really appreciate.

Comment: Did you select "Microsoft Windows" as type of the machine and "Windows 10 (32/64 bit)" as version? Did you select the correct architecture (32 or 64 bit)?

Comment: Yes, i did.. :/

Comment: Did you enable the `efi` option in the mainboard entry?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to install it manually when you can download the virtual box file from M$ official site.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines

If you really want to create new VM from image ensure that VM settings are correct.

- Check if .VDI image is set in Settings > Storage > Sata > Hard Disk
- Check if ISO image is set in   Settings > Storage > Sata > Optical Drive
- Run the VM push F12 and select cd-rom.